# How to compare the data for individual column based on two key columns using sql server 2016?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

**INPUT**

```
 Material    code   description    Name       Process 
   A            1       Test          BioKit     Mixing 
   A            2       Test          BioKit     Mixing    
   A            3       Test                     Mixing    
   A            4       Test123       BioKit     Mixing    
   B            1       Test          BioKit     GRINDING 
   B            2       Test          BioKit234  MixinG
```

I have a table with code and material as key columns for each material the code will be available
here i need to compare the the individual column data suppose for material A
description is same for 3 records and 4 record value is different then we need to display below output
Name is same for all the records even if its contains blank and process also same

for material B description is same no difference and for name field two different values then we need to display below output
Process also different values

**OUTPUT**

```
Material, Description ,  Name ,Process ,code1 ,  code2 , code3, code4 
A          Test123,            ,        ,       ,       ,       , 4 
B       ,           , BioKit234,Mixing  ,       ,   2    ,      ,
```

Can you please give me a hint of how to compare individual column data in a single table, based on the columns material and code?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I do not understand what you like to achieve. Getting always the material with the highest code?

Answer (score 0):

If you like to get the material with the highest code, you could write something like this:

```
WITH HighestCode(Material, Code) AS (SELECT Material, MAX(code) FROM Table2 GROUP BY Material)
SELECT t.* FROM HighestCode hc INNER JOIN Table2 t ON hc.Material = t.Material AND hc.Code = t.Code;
```

which results in

```
Material Code Description Name      Process
-------- ---- ----------- --------- -------
B        2    Test        BioKit234 Mixing
A        4    Test123     BioKit    Mixing
```

Comment: my goal is to get the each column data difference not the highest code.

Comment: I still don't understand what you like to achieve. Somebody understanding what RamaDevi likes to do? Pivoting?

Comment: i need to find  the data difference within that column  for particular material for A material we have data difference in Description right like that i want to find the data difference for each individual column

Comment: The difference to what? The most common entry or to fixed values?

Comment: Ex In the above question for material A description values test ,test, test, test123 three records data is same and the fourth record data is different we need to consider that record as different record these are not fixed values

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure if I understand you right, but this here should point you into the right direction:

I use a material view to simulate a material table, but if you have one, use that:

```
CREATE VIEW Material
AS
SELECT DISTINCT Material FROM Table2
GO
```

Create some helper views for each standard value per material:

```
CREATE VIEW StandardDescription
AS
WITH MostCommon(Material, Description, DescriptionCount) AS (SELECT Material, Description, COUNT(Description) FROM Table2 GROUP BY Material, Description)
SELECT mat.Material, (SELECT TOP 1 Description FROM MostCommon mc WHERE mc.Material = mat.Material ORDER BY DescriptionCount DESC) AS StandardDescription FROM Material mat
GO

CREATE VIEW StandardName
AS
WITH MostCommon(Material, Name, NameCount) AS (SELECT Material, Name, COUNT(Name) FROM Table2 GROUP BY Material, Name)
SELECT mat.Material, (SELECT TOP 1 Name FROM MostCommon mc WHERE mc.Material = mat.Material ORDER BY NameCount DESC) AS StandardName FROM Material mat
GO

CREATE VIEW StandardProcess
AS
WITH MostCommon(Material, Process, ProcessCount) AS (SELECT Material, Process, COUNT(Process) FROM Table2 GROUP BY Material, Process)
SELECT mat.Material, (SELECT TOP 1 Process FROM MostCommon mc WHERE mc.Material = mat.Material ORDER BY ProcessCount DESC) AS StandardProcess FROM Material mat
GO
```

Determine the non-standard rows:

```
CREATE VIEW NonStandardTextsPerMaterial
AS
SELECT t.Material, t.Code, t.Description, NULL AS Name, NULL AS Process FROM Table2 t INNER JOIN StandardDescription v ON t.Material = v.Material WHERE Description != StandardDescription
UNION
SELECT t.Material, t.Code, NULL AS Description, t.Name, NULL AS Process FROM Table2 t INNER JOIN StandardName v ON t.Material = v.Material WHERE Name != StandardName
UNION
SELECT t.Material, t.Code, NULL AS Description, NULL AS Name, t.Process FROM Table2 t INNER JOIN StandardProcess v ON t.Material = v.Material WHERE Process != StandardProcess
GO
```

Cumulate them onto the same row:

```
SELECT Material, Code, MAX(Description) AS Description, MAX(Name) AS Name, Max(Process) AS Process FROM NonStandardTextsPerMaterial GROUP BY Material, Code;
GO
```